# Detect a redirect in RestKit not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, redirect, restkit

I have a web service returning a 302 and the automatic redirect is done by RestKit. I'm trying to do extra logic before the redirect. I know RestKit has `isRedirect` and `isRedirection`. So in the `request:didLoadResponse` delegate I tried to check for it, but it doesn't seem to be hitting any of those. Is there something I'm missing?

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response 
{
    if ([response isRedirection]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"redirection");
    } 
    else if ([response isRedirect])
    {
        NSLog(@"redirect");
    }
    NSLog(@"response %@", [response bodyAsString]);
}
```

Comment: See my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by implementing this:

```
@implementation RKResponse (CustomRedirect)

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)inConnection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)inRedirectResponse 
{
    NSLog( @"redirectResponse ***********************************************");

    NSURLRequest *newRequest = inRequest;
    if (inRedirectResponse) {
        newRequest = nil;
    }
    return newRequest;
}

@end
```

This basically says you want to handle the redirect yourself since you are returning nil. Now the checks for `isRedirect` and `isRedirection` will be hit.

Comment: And how did you get it to not throw a `ld: warning: instance method '...' in category from ... overrides method from class in ...` error?

Comment: That worked for me! Thanks! By the way, I've placed the code in the same class (my project class, NOT restkit class) where I'm creating the RKRequest. Hope that helps. Ciao

Answer (score 2):

I've found an alternative to kailoon way that shoud be a little less "code invasive" for everyone having problems with that solution.
use

```
[request setFollowRedirect:NO]
```

and you should be able to trap the 302 in the requestDidReceiveResponse callback.
It worked for me.

Comment: I'm endorsing this new method as I tested it and it works. This must have been added recently because when I updated my restkit, I started getting a warning about the redirect category I implemented already being implemented by restkit.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread, I know, but just in case anyone comes looking. If you're using RKObjectManager, you can implement `setRedirectResponseBlock` in order to ignore/modify redirects:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request ...etc...];
[operation.HTTPRequestOperation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {
        return redirectResponse ? nil : request;
    }];
[objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

Seems to do the trick.